# Extract 3D array based on 1D array index in C

Tags: c

I have a 1D array `arr = {6,2,1,7}` and 3D array `mat_1`, I need to sort the 1D array in descending order and then extract the 3D array corresponding to max indices of 1D array `index = {3,0,1,2}` as per the below code.

The below code works fine, but I am using an additional memory `mat_2` to copy the elements from `mat_1` and then extract the first `mat_2[0][:][:]` and fourth `mat_2[3][:][:]` data to `mat_1` since the array index `arr[0] and arr[3]` are larger than `arr[1] and arr[2]`.

I'll be working with huge matrices of the order 1024 x 1024 x 20 and I need to avoid additional memory usage like `mat_2`. Kindly suggest an alternative approach to obtain `mat_1` without using `mat_2`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 4
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 4

void sorted_order (int *arr, int n, int *idx);
void swap (int *x, int *y);

int main()
{
    int arr[LENGTH] = {6,2,1,7},idx[LENGTH];
    int mat_1[LENGTH][ROWS][COLS] = {{{6,6,6,6},{6,6,6,6}},{{2,2,2,2},{2,2,2,2}},{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}},{{7,7,7,7},{7,7,7,7}}};
    int mat_2[LENGTH][ROWS][COLS] = {{{0}}};
    int len=LENGTH,half = LENGTH/2,index, row, col;

    //sort array: Array index after sorting = {3,0,1,2}
    sorted_order (arr, len, idx);

    memcpy(mat_2, mat_1, len * sizeof *mat_1);
    for(index = 0; index < half; index++)
    {
        memcpy(mat_1+index,mat_2[idx[index]], len * sizeof *mat_2);
    }

    for(index = 0; index < half; index++){
        for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
                printf("%d\t",mat_1[index][row][col]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first proposal a priori slow

One way is to process by exchanging the values in the same order you do to you sort the 1D array. When you exchange `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` you also exchange `mat_1[i]` and `mat_1[j]`

You don't need to duplicate the 3D array but of course it is more CPU consuming, choose a sort in O(n*log(n))

---

Second proposal a priori faster, using the 1D array index = {3,0,1,2}, you add a 1D array memorizing the indexes in the 3D array, so at the beginning matIdx = {0, 1, 2, 3} then you compare them :

index 0 : you want idx[0]=3 but you have matIdx[0] = 0 => you search in matIdx where is 3 and it is at index 3, so you exchange mat[0] and mat[3], you update matIdx becoming {3,1,2,0}

index 1 : you want idx[1]=0 but you have matIdx[1] = 1 => you search in matIdx where is 0 and it is at index 3, so you exchange mat[1] and mat[3], you update matIdx becoming {3,0,2,1}

index 2 : you want idx[2]=1 but you have matIdx[2] = 2 => you search in matIdx where is 1 and it is at index 3, so you exchange mat[2] and mat[3], you update matIdx becoming {3,0,1,2}

Of course for index 2 it can be simplified because they are the last 2 positions, so there are in order or you just need to exchange, I continued without that optimization to explain

In that way you do at worst n exchanges in mat, the complexity is just to search the indexes in matIdx but this is probably nothing compared to the time to exchange the values in mat

Implementation can be (I do not have your function `sorted_order` so I do not use it) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 4
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 4

/*void sorted_order (int *arr, int n, int *idx);*/

/* exchange mat[i] and mat[j] and update matIdx, i > j */
void swap(int mat[][ROWS][COLS], int matIdx[], int i, int j)
{
  int temp[ROWS][COLS];

  memcpy(temp, mat[j], sizeof(mat[0]));
  memcpy(mat[j], mat[i], sizeof(mat[0]));
  memcpy(mat[i], temp, sizeof(mat[0]));
  matIdx[i] = j;
}

/* return the index in matIdx where what is */
int findIdx(int matIdx[], int from , int what)
{
  while (matIdx[from] != what)
    from += 1;

  return from;
}

int main()
{
    int mat[LENGTH][ROWS][COLS] = {{{6,6,6,6},{6,6,6,6}},{{2,2,2,2},{2,2,2,2}},{{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1}},{{7,7,7,7},{7,7,7,7}}};
    int idx[LENGTH] = {3,0,1,2}; /* idx is normaly set by your function sorted_order */
    int matIdx[LENGTH];
    int index;

    /* initialize matIdx */
    for (index = 0; index != LENGTH; ++index)
      matIdx[index] = index;

    /* sort except the last element */
    for(index = 0; index != LENGTH - 2; index++){
      if (idx[index] != matIdx[index]) {
        // need to exchange
        swap(mat, matIdx, findIdx(matIdx, index + 1, idx[index]), index);
      }
    }

    /* last 2 elements */
    if (idx[LENGTH - 2] != matIdx[LENGTH - 2]) {
      // need to exchange
      swap(mat, matIdx, LENGTH - 1, LENGTH - 2);
    }

    /* print result */
    for(index = 0; index < LENGTH; index++){
      int row;

      for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
        int col;

        for(col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
          printf("%d\t",mat[index][row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution writes :

```
7   7   7   7   
7   7   7   7   

6   6   6   6   
6   6   6   6   

2   2   2   2   
2   2   2   2   

1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Well, to exchange `mat[0]` and `mat[3]`don't we need any additional memory? Could you please explain how to exchange `mat[0]` and `mat[3]`.

Comment: @shannon I need `int[ROWS][COLS]` if I just do 3 memcpy as a standard swap, else can do int per int but is longer

Comment: @shannon I added an implementation

Comment: Excellent ! This is much better than my previous implementation and fast as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic,
it seems that you can skip copying to `mat_2` entirely and just access `mat_1` by using `idx`, like this:

```
for(index = 0; index < half; index++){
        for(row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
            for(col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
                printf("%d\t",mat_1[idx[index]][row][col]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: I think the goal is to modify the 3D array, the final print is just a way to check, this is not the goal

Comment: I'm not sure. shannon talked about extracting values.

Comment: As @bruno mentioned, the print is just a way to check the result and the 3D array needs to be modified or rearranged.